# Changing input variable of function in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a for loop where in each loop it executes a function. Firstly I'm loading `.rda` files from the directory and then want to assign the loaded files (which are data frames) to `spread` and `ind` respectfully. How can I do this? Note that the variable names once get loaded are different in each loop i.e. when #1 is loaded it shows up as `NS.ticker_list[j,2]` and #2 as `Forward.rate.ticker_list[j,2]`.

```
for(j in 1:nrow(ticker_list)){
  load(file = gsub(" ","",paste(ticker_list[j,2],"_NS.rda"))) #1
  load(file = gsub(" ","",paste(ticker_list[j,2],"_Forward.rda"))) #2
  p <- arima.auto.fun(spread, ind, maturity_list, lag = 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load each file into a new environment, convert the environment into a list object, and then assign the first (and only) object in the lists to the `spread` and `ind` variables. You didn't provide a reproducible example, so the following is a rough guess. I've also removed what appears to be an unnecessary use of `gsub` and replaced it with the simpler `paste0`.

```
for(j in 1:nrow(ticker_list)){
  NS_env <- new.env()
  Forward_env <- new.env()
  
  load(file = paste0(ticker_list[j,2],"_NS.rda"), envir = NS_env) #1
  load(file = paste0(ticker_list[j,2],"_Forward.rda"), envir = Forward_env) #2
  
  NS_list <- as.list(NS_env)
  Forward_list <- as.list(Forward_env)
  
  spread <- NS_list[[1]]
  ind <- Forward_list[[1]]
  
  p <- arima.auto.fun(spread, ind, maturity_list, lag = 1)
}
```